# Truth in a different universe of sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

I understand that provability and truth as different concepts.
Provability is syntactic, it only concerns whether the given
sentence can be derived by reiterating the inference rules over a
collection of axioms. Truth, on the other hand, is a model
theoretic notion. Quoted from section 1.3 of [1],

> We say that $A$ is a model of $\phi$, or that $\phi$ is true in
> $A$, if $A \vDash \phi$.

where $A$ is a *structure*, $\phi$ is an atomic formula in the
signature of $A$ without variables, and $\vDash$ defined as
usual. And by saying that $\phi$ is **true**, or $ \vDash \phi$, whenever $A \vDash \phi$ for all structures $A$ (with the same signature).

This question is really about re-examining the definition of
truth, with a specific focus on the definition of structure **since
it depends on what a set means.** So again according to section
1.1 of [1], a structure $A$ is a collection of four **sets**: a set
of domain, a set of constant elements, a set of relation symbols,
and a set of function symbols.

This definition is the one that confuses me the most. In
particular, I wonder what a set means here. In usual mathematics,
we talk about sets based on the ZFC set theory. But there are
other systems such as the ZF set theory, and any other
topoi (in regard that the category of ZFC sets forms a topos)!

Different theory provides a different underlying universe of sets.
Should we change the underlying universe, would we get a
different definition of a structure, and **thus a different
definition of truth?** (Please note that I'm not asking about
taking generalized truth values in some topos.)

#### Reference

[1] A shorter model theory-[Wilfrid Hodges]

Comment: When you read books about algebra, do you worry that there are different definitions of "commutative ring with unit"? After all, a ring is a collection of (around) five sets.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Not really, until I have to start using the fact that they are sets.

Comment: But isn't the situation exactly the same? Why are sets special? By the way, I think it would be more precise to replace the question "are there different definitions of truth?" with "are there different meanings of the definition of truth?" There is literally precisely one definition (for the purposes of this discussion), namely the one written in the textbook you refer to.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I guess it's because most of us are too used to "sets"; so used to them that I started to feel cult-ish, and so used to them that I started to worry what I am secretly assuming when thinking about the notion of *truth*.

Comment: As Joel Hamkins explains, it's not "truth" that fails to be fixed, but the mathematical world you live in. But that's something to rejoice, not worry about.

Comment: @AlecRhea Why did you change a clear title to a worse one?

Comment: @user3840170 I didn’t change it, I rolled back your change; I personally prefer this one, and believe the authors intent should be preserved except in cases of clear errors (mathematical or grammatical). Further, I noticed that after you changed the title the post garnered its first downvote and a vote to close as unclear, and since I rolled back your change it’s gone back to being well received with no further close votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are a variety of mathematical systems that are able to serve as a foundation of mathematics, whether one uses ZFC set theory, ZFC plus large cardinals, or ZF, or PA, or category theory, type theory, and so forth.

Each of these theories is able to provide notions of model, satisfaction, truth, provability (along with all the rest of mathematics, number theory, topology, and so on). In this sense, one can undertake model theory and metamathematics in any of a variety of foundational background theories.

In some cases, different metatheoretic background theories are interpretable within one another, and in these cases, there will be a basic translation of theorems from one system to the other. In other cases, there is at least a relevant conservativity result. For example, ZFC and ZF have exactly the same arithmetic consequences, and this will imply that they have the same proof-theoretic features for any arithmetically definable first-order language. Basically, they will have the same consistency and validity consequences for the usual theories we consider.

Meanwhile, it can also happen that different choices for the background theory can have substantive consequences in the metamathematical features that one finds.

This occurs even just within the various set-theoretic systems. The large cardinal set theories, for example, imply outright that certain theories are consistent, whereas these consistency assertions are not provable in the weaker systems. Not all the systems have exactly the same consistency strength.

In ZFC, for example, the theory PA does not entail Con(PA), but this is not provable in PA alone, since there are models of PA in which PA is thought to be inconsistent, in which case it entails every assertion.

So the different foundational background theories can even disagree on whether a given theory has a given consequence. Thus, they would disagree on whether a given statement is true in all models of the theory.

This can happen even when it isn't just that one system thinks the theory is consistent and the other does not. For example, if one works in $\text{ZFC}+\neg\operatorname{Con}(\text{ZFC})+\rho$ or $\text{ZFC}+\neg\rho$, where $\rho$ is the Rosser sentence for ZFC (or stronger theories, whatever), then these two background theories will satisfy different incompatible $\Sigma_1$ arithmetic assertions. In one theory, the first number with a certain property is of one sort, and in the other, it is of another incompatible sort. So these two theories will both think the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ exists, but they will disagree on what is true in that model.

More generally, in light of the incompleteness theorem, none of the usual systems can be complete for arithmetic truth, and so it is consistent with any of them that they disagree on what is true in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$. Different models of set theory, when used as a metamathematical background context, can have fundamental disagreements on the model theory of our familiar theories.

In summary, yes, the metatheoretic background theory can have consequences as to what is true, what is valid, what is consistent, even for comparatively simple definable models and assertions.

Comment: I wonder how PA could provide a notion of a model. A model should be a structure, which is a 4-tuple of sets; but I don't see how PA could provide a notion of sets..

Comment: PA is a highly robust foundational theory, capable of providing notions of proof, model, and truth in a model. For example, in the natural numbers, you can interpret various mathematical structures ("interpret" is a technical term here, which you might look into). In PA you can prove that every consistent theory has a complete consistent Henkin theory, from which one can interpret a model of that theory, along with the satisfaction relation for truth. Your 4-tuple idea is inappropriately rigid, appropriate in set theory, but not in other theories. Interpreted structure is where it's at.

Comment: I also thought that the 4-tuple sets definition is inappropriately rigid! However, most model theory books are introductory, and they stick to this sort of definition (even without mentioning it explicitly). Could you recommend some references on model theory that deals with a more general definition of structures and models, discusses model theories based on different theories (PA, ZF(C), category.. etc), and compares how they differ?

Comment: Most of the standard model theory books are using set theory as the background theory, and so naturally they use the standard 4-tuple definition (which goes back many decades). But if you are entertaining the idea of doing model theory in another foundation, you need to develop the ideas anew in that foundation. This exists, but I am less familiar with this literature.

Comment: Except for the PA case, where there is a lot of work on arithmetized completeness theorem etc., which is about how to do model theory in PA for infinite structures.

Comment: But actually, even in the set theory context, most model theorists I know are not dogmatic about how the models are represented in set theory. It would be a false criticism to suggest that set-theoretic model theory insists on a particular formalism in that regard.

Comment: Meanwhile, it seems that you are concerned about a relatively easy matter, when the different conceptions of model, proof, truth, etc. are mutually interpretable or even bi-interpretable within one anothey (as they are for the various natural ways to implement these ideas in any of the foundational systems). My answer, however, is in part about a far more troubling philosophical matter, which occurs when the foundational systems do not agree on the notions of truth and validity.

Comment: I try to paraphrase and complete a paragraph of yours. Could you please let me know if it is accurate, in order for a better understanding? :: In *the metalanguage* ZFC, for example, the theory PA does not entail Con(PA), but this is not provable in PA alone, since there are models *(in the metalanguage ZFC)* of PA in which PA is thought to be inconsistent, in which case it entails every assertion. :: If this is accurate, that should mean that we cannot produce a model of PA (in the metalanguage PA) that is inconsistent; right? If so, is there any reference? I'd like to dive deeper in this.

Comment: PA does not prove it's own consistency, and so one cannot prove in PA that there is any model of PA. However, in PA+Con(PA), we can prove that there is a model of PA, and indeed a model of PA+¬Con(PA). This is just basic stuff about the completeness theorem and incompleteness theorem which is in any good logic book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151532/discussion-between-student-and-joel-david-hamkins).

Comment: Sorry, I don't care to talk in chat, and I think I've made my contribution here as much as I shall. If you have further questions about these elementary matters in mathematical logic, I would suggest you ask on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 12):

In contrast to Joel's answer, I would like to point out that the notion of truth-in-a-structure, or whether $A \models \phi$ for a given $A,\phi$, is not so wild and capricious.  Although the question of whether $\phi$ is true in all models of a given theory $T$ of course depends on what models of $T$ exist, given a particular one $A$, the satisfaction relation is relatively concrete.  One just needs to establish the notion recursively on the complexity of formulas.

For any particular formula $\phi$, one can write down a step-by-step procedure for checking whether a given model $A$ satisfies $\phi$.  If $H$ is a larger structure (of set theory) with $A \in H$, and $H$ satisfies a very basic set theory like Kripke-Platek, so that it can do basic operations like pairing and union and taking subsets defined by simple ($\Delta_0$) formulas, then $H$ will reach the same conclusion about whether $A \models \phi$ as any other $H'$ with the same properties.

Even the notion of whether $A \models T$, for theories $T$ possessing infinitely many formulas, is highly absolute.  One just needs the machinery to carry out the definition of satisfaction for *all* formulas in the language of $T$, which involves a recursion of length $\omega$.  So any two mathematical universes possessing $A$ will agree on whether $A \models T$ as long as they have **standard** $\omega$ and can carry out recursions of length $\omega$ where each step involves constructing a subset defined by a simple formula (like taking complements, intersections, cartesian projections).

(Someone more familiar with weak set theories might want to improve this answer by getting more specific and dropping some keywords...)

**EDIT:** I should acknowledge the interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0670.pdf) of Hamkins and Yang, where they show that you can have two models with the same (nonstandard) natural numbers that disagree on whether some (nonstandard) sentence is satisfied by the natural number structure.  The point, as I understand it, is that the inductive notion of satisfaction is not completely determined by the starting point when you get into nonstandard numbers.  Thus I should have specified above in the first version that satisfaction of a *standard* theory by a model is absolute between universes  with *standard* $\omega$.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but it seems that you're suggesting that even if *truth* depends on the underlying universe of sets, *usually* changing the universe doesn't alter whether $\phi$ is true (i.e. $\vDash \phi$). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm saying that the *model-theoretic notion of truth* does not depend very much on the background universe.

Comment: @Student Also, it is important to note that by Gödel's completeness theorem, $\phi$ being provable from a theory $T$ is *equivalent* to $\phi$ being true in all models of $T$.  So in this sense, when we quantify over all models, truth and provability become the same.